# VST for Cordova only support API Level 19?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

The requirements for the Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova specify that SDK for the API Level 19 must be installed. Do that means that apps created with it will only run on android KitKat devices? Any way to target older devices?

Please review the following article for reference:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757054.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cordova targets a single SDK (currently 19 though a upcoming release will move this to 21). However this is just the SDK used to build - by default Cordova apps can be deployed on devices running API level 10 or higher (2.3.3). Unless you're creating a custom plugin that will use an API only available on Android 5.0, you won't be affected by the SDK used.

The Android tab on the config.xml designer allows you to set alternate values for what goes in  "AndroidManifest.xml" file, but the build itself will always use SDK 19.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Comment: @ Chuck Lantz In VS 2015 I have the Android sdk Api levels 19, 21, 22, 23 installed. However, when I try the kitkat emulators (4.4) in  Visual Studio it tells me "command failed with exit code 1", that should  depend on the target version. Do you know what I should do in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Android 4.4.x (API level 19) is required by Visual Studio to build app or create app package targeting Android platform not for running the app. You can create Cordova app targeting device running Android released before KitKat.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Could you please elaborate on the steps to choose the target api level from visual studio?